# Determine Difference Between NULL, ZERO (double) and value (double)

Tags: php, mysqli

As both NULL and 0 return as empty in php, I'm struggling to determine the difference based on double type results from a mysqli recordset.

I've tried converting each scenario in order to return a more manageable returned string:

```
if($val == 0){
   echo "No Cost Option";
} elseif (empty($val)){
   echo "UNCOSTED";
} else {
   echo "£ ".number_format($val ,2);
}
```

Theoretically, if a zero is present in the DB, it should return "No Cost Option".

Equally then, if the DB comes back with NULL, it should return "UNCOSTED".

Finally, if there is a value, it will simply format that value.

Currently (and incorrectly), both NULLs and 0s are being treated the same way so both get processed as "No Cost Option".

Comment: @Dharman - Did not know that - thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strictly compare to `null`. If you strictly compare to integer it might not work, because the result would be a numeric string.

Reverse your if statement order and check for null first.

```
if (null === $val) {
    echo "UNCOSTED";
} elseif ($val == 0) {
    echo "No Cost Option";
} else {
    echo "£ ".number_format($val, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you strictly want to compare to the number 0 your should use **===**

```
if($val === 0){
   echo "No Cost Option";
} elseif (empty($val)){
   echo "UNCOSTED";
} else {
   echo "£ ".number_format($val ,2);
}
```

You use === to get a strict identical comparison (Type & value).

If you want more precision,

0, null, false, "0", [] (an empty array) and more (see [type comparaison](https://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)) are equal in value.
So

```
0 == null == false == "0" == array()
```

But they are not if you compare they type with **===**

Comment: FYI the results from mysqli will come always as a string or null. If you compare `'0'===0` it will return false.

Comment: Hmmm - this answer actually causes issues if the value is zero. It returns "uncosted". @Dharman his answer seems to work consistently.

Comment: Well that's what i'm saying when I say that 0=='0'==false but return false when using ===

Comment: Is it zero (0) or "0" which is not the same. You ask for zeros in your question and not a "0" which is probably what it is since as @Dharman says the results from mysqli will come always as a string or null

Comment: @DylanKas it was indeed a zero (0), not a "0".